# Why is my cube in Blender just lines in the shape of a cube?

Tags: 3d-view

I don't know what I did but I looked back at my screen at first, the cube was transparent but I don't know what I pressed for it to become a line. I looked it up and they said, in *Edit Mode*, select everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>M</kbd> and *By Distance*"

[image: description here]

Answer (score 0):

Click on an object, press <kbd>Z</kbd> and go around the circle pie menu until you see `Solid` and that should fix it.

Comment: ...or Shift-Z to switch directly between Solid and Xray mode.

Comment: ...also alt+z to turn off X-ray mode.

Comment: @JohnEason You mean wireframe mode right?

Comment: @TheKalaakaar Yes! My mistake! :^(  Shift-Z toggles Wireframe **and** X-ray mode on and off if X-ray isn't already turned on with Alt-Z. You can see that from the top-right icons on the toolbar.